# clojure how to execute a function on elements of two seqs concurently?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, what is the best way for iterating concurrently on two seqs and calling a function on the two running elements?
For example:

```
(def a (range 3))
(def b (range 100 103))
(defn my-func [] ...) ;some custom code
```

The code should execute my-func 3 times, like this:

```
(my-func 0 100)
(my-func 1 101)
(my-func 2 102)
```

How can I achieve that without defining any function or macro?

Comment: (range 100 102) only has two elements - perhaps you mean (range 100 103)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`map` is exactly what you need, it takes a function and any number of seqs and calls them just as you wish.

```
(def a (range 3))
(def b (range 100 103))
user=> a
(0 1 2)
user=> b
(100 101 102)

user=> (defn my-func [a b] (str a ":" b))
#'user/my-func

user=> (my-func 1 2)
"1:2"

user=> (map my-func a b)
("0:100" "1:101" "2:102")
```

and because `map` is lazy if you want the function to actually run now:

```
(doall (map my-func a b))
```

Comment: @viebel: Are you running at the REPL and using `println`? If so, your results are confusing. Assuming you ran `(map #(println %1 ":" %2) a b)`, what happened is that the REPL printed `(`, then `println` printed the `0 : 100` and `1 : 101`, then the REPL finished printing the results of the map, which is `nil nil)`.

Comment: @Arthur Ulfeldt:The whole point of my question is to seek for a way to iterate without creating a map. println is just an example. The code I seek for should work with any function that receives 2 args. Should I edit the question in order to clarify it?

Comment: @viebel: `map` does what you wish, but the results of `println` are interspersed with the REPL output. `(map f a_1 a_2 ... a_n)` calls `f` with arguments taken from the seqs `a_1` to `a_n` and returns the results in a new `seq`. `println` returns a `nil`, so `map`ping `println` over collections gives `(nil nil ... nil)` as a result.

Comment: As an example: `(map + [1 2 3] [6 2 9] [9 2 2])` => `(16 6 14)`

Comment: @mange: I wrote a short file containing: (map println '(1 2) '(10 20)). When executing it, it does nothing!!!

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit: `map` is lazy (see [the page on clojure.org](http://clojure.org/lazy), or [sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences) has a bit too), so it won't evaluate until it needs the results (which is also why the REPL stuff intersperses). It's very handy, but can trip you up in times like this. Try `(doall (map println '(1 2) '(10 20)))`. `doall` forces evaluation of the `seq` passed to it.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try

```
(doseq [[x y] (map list my-list1 my-list2)]
  (println x y))
```

`(map list list-2 list-2)` creates a list where the first element is a list of the first elements of the input lists, the second element is a list of the second elements, ...

We then iterate over the list, using Clojure's destructuring to extract the elements of the original lists.

In general, you want `map` if you want to use the return value of the function you are applying.  If you are merely executing a function for its side effects, I generally use `doseq`.  This case is complicated by the fact that `map` works in parallel, while `doseq` iterates over the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the lists it is given, so you need both `map` and `doseq` to get the behavior we want.

Comment: Is there any doseq-like function that iterates in parallel and not over the cartesian product. If no, what is the rationale behind it?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such function.  Ideally doseq/for (they share the same syntax) would allow something like an :and option to allow for two seqs to iterate in parallel.  Unfortunately, such an option doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `(doseq ... (map` solution, if you want pairwise iteration instead of cartesian product, you can also combine `partition` with `interleave` like this:

```
> (def a (range 0 3))
> (def b (range 100 103))
> (interleave a b)
(0 100 1 101 2 102)
> (partition 2 (interleave a b))
((0 100) (1 101) (2 102))
```

The `partition` call provides a (lazy) seq of pairs.